# Generating points with specific distance properties

Tags: point, intersection, qgis-2, lines-to-points

I have a layer with multiple lines. I want to generate points at each intersection which is easy with the Geoprocessing tools. The next step however is giving me issues;

From each intersection of two or more lines I want to generate points with equal distance to the intersection on all lines intersecting.

[image]

I can create the point (x,y) but want to make sure that (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2). (x_3, y_3), (x_4, y_4) are the exact same distance from the intersection point no matter the shape length.

Is there any smart way of doing these steps?

Answer (score 1):

What about buffering your central intersection point, converting buffer polygons to lines and intersecting those buffer lines with your original lines?